# How to stylize text between backticks ( ` ) to match text style between single/double quotes ( ' | " )?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

In my vim, I'm using gruvbox. Syntax colorization is great for everything except text written between `backticks`. You'll note once backticks are used, all subsequent lines of text are green.  I would like backtick text to behave just like standard quoted text and to not screw up highlighting for the rest of the file. I write a lot of JavaScript. Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: ```:call matchadd("String", "`\.\*`")``` This command add pattern "any characters between backticks, backticks included" to String highlight-group.
```:he matchadd```
```:he pattern```
```:hi```

Comment: This is more likely to be an issue with the syntax file. Contact the maintainers of whichever syntax file you use and ask them to fix it. One way to help debug is to figure out the syntax groups around the broken area.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - Issue opened here: https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/issues/284 Go vote it up!

Comment: @azatar thats the colorscheme. I was referring to the syntax file for javascript.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - You're right. My mistake. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the keen [@D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble), I did some deeper digging into Javascript syntax... and found a vim plugin tailored specifically to Javascript called [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript).

I installed it into the `my_plugins` directory inside my `.vim_runtime` folder that tunes [The Ultimate Vim Configuration](https://github.com/amix/vimrc), which I also love more than any IDE so far.

That did the job swimmingly.

[image: It works.]